# Trigger component re-render in React with Redux after external script initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to trigger a re-render of my React component after an external script has been initialized (because the external script is defining some window variables that are used in the component).

Currently I have this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    ...
});

class App extends Component {
    handleForceUpdate() {
        console.log('forcing update');
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('externalScriptInitialized', this.handleForceUpdate.bind(this));
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('externalScriptInitialized', this.handleForceUpdate);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

When triggering `externalScriptInitialized`, "forcing update" is logged to the console. So the event is working, but the component is not re-rendering. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a typical example of the usage of a local state.

Would something like this suit your need?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
const App = () => {
  const [isExternalScriptInitialized, setIsExternalScriptInitialized] = useState(false);

  // Listen to external script
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScriptMessage = () => {
      setIsExternalScriptInitialized(true)
    }
    window.addEventListener('externalScriptInitialized', handleScriptMessage)

    return window.removeEventListener('externalScriptInitialized', handleScriptMessage)
  }, [])

  return isExternalScriptInitialized
    ? <div>Script is ready</div>
    : <div>Waiting for script to load</div>
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to this which works in a class component?

Comment: Class components are just there to ensure retro compatibility and should not be used anymore. But you could replicate the principle with a local state and `this.setState`. Again, this is not recommended

Comment: Thanks for you replies. Changing my main App component to a functional component is not an option at the moment, and there are multiple child components which rely on the state update, but using this useEffect solution everywhere will be a bit tedious. However I can't get a local state update to re-render the component in my App component using this.setState. What I've done is basically to change this.forceUpdate to this.setState({initialized: true}) in my original code, as well as defining state in the constructor, but not working. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The contract of `setState` is to rerender a react component so as is, I'm afraid I cannot identify what causes the fact it is not rerendering. Have you declared `this.state` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes I've declared this.state in the constructor.

Comment: Ah I see what the problem is now... The App component is re-rendering, but not the child components. Any solution to this?

Comment: You could pass the `this.state.initialized` as a prop to the child component so it will actually rerender as it changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working now. Hopefully this is not considered as a super ugly hack, especially since that prop is not being used anywhere.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you could move the whole listening logic into the child component if it is the only one actually needing it. Again, this would be much simpler with hooks and function component as you could extract the whole logic into a hook and use it anywhere you want throughout the app. Maybe you could extract the logic in several functions and use these in the components that would need it but it would be pretty difficult and cryptic

Comment: Yeah though the thing is that there are multiple child components, so that would require the same logic in multiple places.